# Splitting field of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z_3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

Let $E$ be the splitting field of $f(x)=x^4-x-2 $ over $\mathbb{Z_3}$ determine $[E:\mathbb{Z_3}]$ and factor $f(x)$ in linear factors in $E[x]$

It's clear that $2$ is a root of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z_3}$, hence we can write $f(x)=(x-2)(x^3+2x^2+x+1)$ in $E[x]$, I'm unsure how I could go on from here since the cubic we got it's not easily factorable, it should have a real root and two complex conjugate solutions.

How can I determine $[E:\mathbb{Z_3}]$? and how could I factor further? The solution presented on the notes where I found the exercise states the following factorization: $f(x)=(x-2)(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^3)(x-\alpha^9)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3+2x^2+x+1$

Comment: “it should have a real root and two complex conjugate solutions”:  are you factoring over field $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb Z_3$?  If a cubic has no roots, it’s irreducible

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I apologize, clearly we're not interessed in what the roots are in $\mathbb{C}$, I just couldn't figure out how one would factor it in $\mathbb{Z_3}$ so I thought maybe it's factorization in $\mathbb{C}$ could tell us something valuable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $\mathbb{Z}_3$ refers to the finite field with $3$ elements. First show that $g=x^3+2x^2+x+1$ is irreducible. Note that it is a degree $3$ polynomial, so it is sufficient to show that it has no roots (in $\mathbb{Z}_3$).
So you know there is a degree $3$ extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ in which $g$ has a root $\alpha$. Now show that this is already a splitting field of $g$ and therefore a splitting field of $f$ and determine the conjugates of $\alpha$ in order to factor $f$.
Hint for this part: Extension of finite fields are Galois-extensions. What is the Galois group?

Comment: Now it's clear to me that $[E:\mathbb{Z_3}]=3$ since $g$ is clearly irreducible over $\mathbb{Z_3}$. On the other hand we still haven't covered Galois Theory in my course, so I suppose that's why I couldn't really figure out where that factorization came from...

Comment: @SpasojeDurovic Galois theory isn't really needed to prove this, it would just make things a bit easier/quicker. If you want to do it without: Prove that if $\alpha$ is a root of $g$, so ist $\alpha^3$. (Hint for this: Show that the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is a homomorphism of fields that acts as the identity on $\mathbb{Z}_3$).

Comment: And argue why we cannot have $\alpha=\alpha^3$ if $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Z}_3$